# How to confirm iOS device has uploaded/synced all photos+videos to iCloud Photo Library?

Tags: ios, icloud, photos, data-synchronization, data-transfer

How do I confirm an iOS device has uploaded/synced all photos+videos to iCloud Photo Library?

**Details**

I have yet to find a way to determine explicit status of the iCloud upload/backup/sync similarly to the 'Backup complete' explicit status that the Google Photos iOS app provides.

I can login to iCloud.com and see what photos/videos exist, and *hope* that, if the latest-dated photo/video on my iOS device is also found in iCloud.com, that *all* the photos/videos are saved in Cloud. However, this would not account for the iCloud Photo Library syncing the photo/video files "out of order" (like Google Photos seems to do, apparently syncing the largest photos/videos last).

For my immediate purposes, 'iOS device' = iPhone8 running iOS 11.1.

**EDIT**

I notice now at the bottom of the iOS Photos app this status:

[image: Photos.app uploading status]

However, the upload has seemingly been stuck on '217 Items' indefinitely, even while connected to fast Wifi (speedtest.net-tested to be 10+ Mbps upload) and while the iPhone8 is externally powered. I also power-cycled the iPhone, and no change in behavior. I added a photo, counted incremented to 218, then quickly when back down to 217... and stayed there. What gives?

Comment: iCloud is a syncing solution and not really a backup solution. It does its work when there's available time, bandwidth, and resources so you won't see immediate updates.  It's main job is to allow you access from all your signed-in devices. Be sure you have available space in iCloud (you didn't mention free space), too.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have 100's of GB of free space on my iCloud account. The uploading has been stuck on "Uploading 217 items" for at least 5 hours now. I doubt it's a "iCloud is slow and not meant to be a backup solution" issue. I think some other obstacle is causing it to be overtly "stuck." But I speculate. Thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: Try leaving it plugged-in and on the wifi overnight and see if there's any change.  Make sure your device has the proper date & time.  None of those work, sign out of iCloud and back in again.

Comment: Thanks @fsb.  My phone status has not budged off of the 217-item "stuck" mode all day. I have signed out of iCloud, signed back in, and I plan on performing the procedure presented at my question (linked below( sometime soon.  (And if iCloud doesn't get all my photos, oh well, I've grown tired of waiting for it.)

https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/336356/13179

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force a Photo Stream sync on the iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46243/how-can-i-force-a-photo-stream-sync-on-the-iphone)

Comment: The question title asks something else than the question text. If this topic is still something you are looking for answers for, please edit the question.

Comment: @nohillside - I believe the title and text are aligned.

Comment: ankiiiiiii - my question is similar (to the other), but the answers (in the other question) do not yet appear to answer my question.

Comment: All- StackExchange continues to lose mind share from valuable contributors (like me) to Reddit and other communities due to SE policies and the _perception_ from users (like me) of less-thougthful, overzealous admins.

SE can of course do what it pleases. It will do it with less contribution from me.

All of everyone's hard work and effort is appreciated, in any case. We're all working hard to do the best thing possible for the things we believe in.

Thank you for everyone's contributions.

Comment: The title asks about "how to confirm that all photos have been uploaded", the edit basically answers that and adds a new question about why the process seems to be stuck (and implicitly how to restart a stuck process). So it's a bit difficult to see what a possible answer could be.